# PHP return msqli_fetch_assoc from a function

Tags: php, mysqli, return-value

I have a function in PHP that executes a query and returns the resutls:

```
public function findUsersByParentId ( $parentId ) {

    $query = " SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.parent_id = " .$parentId ;

    $con = DBHelper::getDatabaseConnection();
    $queryResult = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $results = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);        
    mysqli_close($con);

    return $results;
}
```

and then I want to loop through the results in another file:

```
....
$values = $UserModel->findUsersByParentId ( $parentId );   
foreach ( $values as $row ) {
     echo $row['id'] . " : " . $row['name'];
}
```

but it does not work. If if use the print-loop inside the first function if prints Ok. If I use the print-loop with the "return"ed results it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: From what I see your `findUsersByParentId` will only return at most one user. And that seems a VERY inefficient way to use database connection.

Comment: No. My query will return ALL users that have the specified parent_id

Comment: Define *does not work*. Have you check `var_dump($values);` ?

Comment: Neither does this answer show any help effort. I have search a lot the past 24 hours for this.

Comment: Don't tell me that in these 24 hours you **never** ever visited **manual page** for this function.

Comment: of course I have checked the manual and I have previously used it as:

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['id'] . " : " . $row['name'];
    }

but it prints only if I use it inside the "findUsersByParentId" function. If I use this loop outside using the return of that function it does not work as a loop of assoc array.

Comment: Yes, on second glance it's rather logical failure.

Comment: For some reason you aren't using this loop outside, but using something else. Yet you complains it doesn't work. Seems quite illogical to me

Comment: Why is it illogical? I return the same array I would print with the loop from "findUsersByParentId". I loop the returned array in another function the same way.

Comment: Quite contrary. You don't return the same array and you don't loop over it. Let me draw your attention to the fact that the word "while" hardly resembles the word "foreach", for example.

Comment: @Panos [`mysqli_result::fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) will only return **ONE** row from database result. That's why I said you will get at most one user per function call. And your previous effect (using while-loop inside function) is (one of) a right way.

Answer (score 0):

`$results = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` will only get one row at a time.

so you have to do something like:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   $results[]=$row;
   }
return $results;
```